# Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing 'RNCDatePicker' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered

Tags: android, react-native, datepicker, expo, datetimepicker

While trying to use "DateTimePicker" from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker', am getting the below error.

ERROR  Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNCDatePicker' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
  [image]

You can find the project here https://github.com/mendismenon/md_reactnative.

I was follwing the below video to implement this feature.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEfFjfW7Zes

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the issue

It is [related to android only phone](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/808),

You can fix it by downgrading temporary expo

```
npm install expo@^48.0.0
```

and then

```
npx expo install --fix
```

Comment: I have done the opposite, keeping expo 49 and downgrading the datetime picker package to this one and it work for both Android and iOS :

@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3

Comment: guys I downgraded and it gave me new headaches I had to revert to my previous commit. do this with caution if you're going to try

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answered comments so far - I was able to fix this error also.

When I was starting the project I got this warning:

```
...
Starting Metro Bundler
Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo version:
  react-native-svg@14.1.0 - expected version: 13.9.0
  @react-native-community/datetimepicker@7.6.2 - expected version: 7.2.0
  @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.21.0 - expected version: 1.18.2
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
Fix with: npx expo install --fix
```

As the people suggested I modified my package.json like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    ....
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2"
  },
```

Basically what I did is to downgrade the versions of datetimepicker and async-storage to match the versions from the warning message.

Then I ran:

```
npx expo install --fix 
npm install
```

And this fixed my issue. Good luck!